# Как получить новый стандарт C++20?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, c++14, c++20

пишу на c++ в visual studio 2017, совершенно недавно понял, что у меня очень старый стандарт c++98, но как так? Вроде бы пишу в visual studio 2017, так где же c++17 или c++20? Как мне перейти на новый стандарт, НЕ обновляя свою IDE до 2019 года? Можете рассказать об этом по подробнее.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << __cplusplus;
    return 0;
}
```

Собираю этот код и на выводе получаю это:[image: Вывод 199711]

Comment: C++20 там точно нет (только некоторые экспериментальные фичи) так как она вышла до него. Так что обновляйтесь. [таблица соответствия стандарту](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019)

Comment: В чем проблема обновить среду?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Visual Studio 2017 достаточно указать в командной строке требуемый стандарт (до 17) - запустите `cl /?`, и увидите, в частности,

> ```
>                            -ЯЗЫК-
> ```
>
> `/std:<c++14|c++17|c++latest> стандартная версия C++`
> `c++14 - ISO/IEC 14882:2014 (по умолчанию)`
> `c++17 - ISO/IEC 14882:2017`
> `c++latest - последний черновик стандарта (набор возможностей может быть изменен)`

Этот ключ может быть указан в самой операционной системе в переменной среды `CL`, например,

```
set CL=/std:c++latest
```

Соответствующие настройки доступны и в IDE. Меню Проект->Свойства->Свойства конфигурации->С/С++->Язык->Стандарт языка С++

Насколько я помню, в первых выпусках VC++ 2017 по умолчанию использовался C++11, но могу и ошибаться. В последней версии по умолчанию используется С++14, но можно переключиться на С++17.

Что до C++20 - боюсь, в VC++ 2017 - никак... [Здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019) вы можете ознакомиться с тем, что из стандарта и в какой версии VC++ было реализовано.

Comment: В таком случае, как мне можно получить c++17? Потому что когда я решил воспользоваться std::string_view, то IDE сообщила, что такой тип отсутствует, перед этим я подключил #include <string_view>. Хотя в c++17 они есть.

Comment: По-моему, я ясно указал, как - `/std:c++17`. Или в настройках проекта - опять же, см. ответ. Еще - вот здесь - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019 - что и в какой версии VC++ реализовано.

Answer (score 4):

Вы, вероятно, неправы относительно текущей версии стандарта - этот макрос [по умолчанию рапортует](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=vs-2019) о наличии 1997 версии ради обеспечения совместимости

> ```
> Because lots of existing code appears to depend on the value of this
> macro matching "199711L", the compiler does not change the value of
> the macro unless you explicitly opt-in by using the /Zc:_
> ```

А чтобы проверить версию c использованием этого макроса, нужно включить опцию компилятора `/Zc`

> ```
> When the /Zc:__cplusplus option is enabled, the value reported by the 
> __cplusplus macro depends on the /std version switch setting.
> ```